# CakePHP 3.x beforeFind() callback, when it fire?

Tags: cakephp, orm, callback, cakephp-3.0

I use CakePHP `beforeFind()` callback for my Tables ain this way:

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options, $primary)
{
    // if ->applyOptions(['default' => false]) not use default conditions
    if(isset($options['default']) && $options['default'] == false){
        return $query;
    }

    $query->where(['visible' => 1]);

    $query->order(['sort' => 'ASC']);

    return $query;
}
```

And this is correct, BUT WHEN i try to retrieve my result sometimes it fired and sometimes no.

`NO` - I think that if i use table registry for get my table: `TableRegistry::get('MyTable')->find()->first()` its not fired.

`YES` - And if i use, from same controller, `$this->Pages->find()->first()` its fired!

**Its work in this way only for me?** Or for have the beforeFind() fired i need to do some additional stuff?

Comment: Are you sure that the string you're passing for `MyTable` is correct? Cake may be creating a scaffolded model for you if that name is wrong.

Comment: Man you right! I call my file with a singular name `BannerTable.php` instead of plural `BannersTable.php` thank you very much! My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your fields are not ambiguous as part of your query. Try adding the name of the model in the where queries, otherwise you'll get PDOExceptions:

`$query->where(['myModel.visible'=>1]);`

Comment: Yes it also a good practice, but my mistake was discovered by @Greg Schmidt i call the file with a wrong name